# android purchase in app money not received

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, aidl

I want to add an android in-app payment method, so I followed instructions by this page using [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api)

I successfully added it and tried to do an effective payment using my personal google account. The payment was successful but I didn't receive the money.

I know that, implementing this type of purchase, a user can buy add-on app features or simply make a small donation. Isnt' it? Is there a better method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As Google say in [billing testing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing): To test your Google Play Billing implementation with actual in-app purchases, you must use a test account. By default, the only test account registered is the one that's associated with your developer account.

Money not charged if you account equivalent to you Google Play account.

Also you can try to use more convenient [library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview) from google for in-app billing

Comment: Thanks for your reply Onix... So, how do I test if the money will be charge? I must ask to my friend to do a test?

Comment: If you want to be sure that money come to you account - yes, just buy goods from account not listed as tester in you Google Play Account.